# Which provide the best grid performance Angular Grid or Slik Grid or any other?

Tags: wijmo, slik, angular-grid

I was planning to make a **grid based application**. i have 2 main requirements:-

1-**performance**
2-**Some Excel type look and functionality**.

I was thinking about angular js.
But i have heard that angular js with angular grid has very bad performance issue.

I also have heard that performance can be better if i use only hybrid angular grid without using angular js.
But it may affect my functionalities.

**Guys any ideas? 
what should i use?**

Comment: In order to ask this question here in a proper way, you could post setup information for both / any / all grid systems, with a range of data, and associated benchmark data for these permutations on one or more browers+platforms.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out Wijmo 5 FlexGrid which fulfills both of your requirements. Here is the demo link:
http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/Explorer/Explorer/#/grid/intro
http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/FlexGridIntro/FlexGridIntro/

and also, the benchmark sample:
http://demos.componentone.com/wijmo/5/Angular/Benchmark/Benchmark/

Comment: We are using wijmo grid, it's aweful

Answer (score 0):

> Excel type and functionality.

It depends on your knowledge about css and js. But i think it is not so much work.

While deciding which framework to use, you may have better criterias (*e.g. performance, activeness of the community, parametrisability, level of utilizing the angular framework etc.*)

For all my criterias, i think [ui-grid](http://ui-grid.info/) is the best.